# ways to format my date with 24hr

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Could someone please show me a way in SQL and C# to format my date string like the following?

```
2/24/2012 22:00
```

Note: I don't need the seconds.

given:

```
declare @myDate varchar(50)
set @myDate = '2/24/2012 10:00 PM'

select @myDate
```

I'm showing the code snippet above to indicate that the date's source type is varchar.

Comment: Both?  There's SQLCLR too =)  Assuming SQL Server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL, you can try:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
SET @date = CONVERT(DATETIME, @myDate, 20);
SELECT convert(varchar(10), @date, 101) + convert(varchar(5), @date, 114);
```

For C#,

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse('2/24/2012 10:00 PM');
String newDateStr = convertedDate.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: Please don't use `varchar` without specifying the length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can pass parameters to the ToString() method to get exactly what you want. It's well documented here: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

According to that you should try:

```
myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: become familiar with DateTime's overridden ToString() method.  It comes in handy.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server <= 2008 R2, you can say:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, @myDate), 101) 
+ ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(5),  CONVERT(DATETIME, @myDate), 8)
```

However this will yield leading zeros that you don't seem to want (and that nobody else seemed to catch). If you want to keep your m/d/yyyy format (which isn't advisable anyway - better to use a language- and region-ambiguous format like yyyy-mm-dd), you might be best off just keeping that portion of the string as is, and just converting the time as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), CONVERT(DATETIME, '10:00 PM'), 8);
```

Of course for an arbitrary date you can brute force it as follows:

```
SELECT RTRIM(MONTH(@myDate)) + '/' + RTRIM(DAY(@myDate)) + '/' + RTRIM(YEAR(@myDate))
```

Combining those of course translates to, in C#:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
```

In SQL Server 2012, you will be able to use almost identical syntax in T-SQL:

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'M/d/yyyy HH:mm');
```

Result at time of writing:

```
2/25/2012 00:38
```

(I [blogged about the new `FORMAT()` capabilities last August](https://sqlblog.org/2011/08/09/sql-server-v-next-denali-ctp3-t-sql-enhancements-format) when I first saw the feature in CTP3. It's pretty powerful stuff.)

You can see a table showing all of the valid styles to use with `CONVERT` in [this FAQ article I wrote in 2003](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-are-the-valid-styles-for-converting-datetime-to-string.html). I also describe how you can make your own functions [in a different FAQ article](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/can-i-make-sql-server-format-dates-and-times-for-me.html), but it doesn't explicitly cover the format you're after again because of the leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient way of doing this, but I think it should work:

```
declare @myDate varchar(50)
set @myDate = '2/24/2012 10:00 PM'

DECLARE @thisDate DATETIME
SET @thisDate = CAST(@myDate AS DATETIME)

SELECT CONVERT (NVARCHAR(10),@thisDate, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @thisDate, 8)
```

Comment: `NVARCHAR`? Why would you need varying length, or Unicode? 101 will never produce a date with umlauts or Arabic. :-)